# Passport with all pages full

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

My USA passport pages are all full. On my entry into Germany I was reminded that entry to another country can be denied. My trip includes another country before returning home.

Comment: If you're only going to another Schengen country, you'll be fine. And a lot of countries don't care; they will just find a spot somewhere and stamp.

Comment: If you have enough time in Germany, you can get a new passport at a US Consulate there and continue your trip instead of returning to the US first, but you'd need to contact them to see when they can take you and how long it would take.

Comment: Most importantly, **what other country** are you planning to visit?

Comment: I have had this before also. It's for sure Karlson's answer below is right.

Comment: I've had a visa denied because the stamp would have to slightly overlap another stamp. I don't think they were looking for baksheesh either, just bureaucratic so-and-so's (Indian consulate).

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 24):

As of [January 1st, 2016](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/news/visa-pages-no-longer-issued.html) your only option is to get a new passport.  If you travel frequently you can request a 52 page passport book but if you run out of those you will need another passport again.

Comment: Actually if they renew at a foreign post (consulate, embassy) they automatically get a 52 pager.  Only renewals done in the USA can choose a 24 or 52 page version.

Comment: @Tom is that new? I renewed my passport at the US embassy in Germany and got to choose, and picked a 24 page one. A relative did the same thing last year and forgot to check either option in the form, and got the 52 page version.

Comment: @jdm - Not sure how new the policy is.  I was told that by the consul in Thailand last year and it is also stated in the link Karlson provided.  The consul mentioned they did it because folks who renew overseas, tend to be folks who travel a lot and need more pages (they comprised the bulk of folks who used to get extra pages added as well, like me).  It wouldn't surprise, however, if there were embassies that had different policies.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that "another country" is not in Schengen (if it is, there is no passport check between that country and Germany, and you will only have two stamps), you have very few options besides those already listed in other answers:

1. You can get a new passport quickly from the US Embassy when you're abroad (most likely this would be a temporary passport). They are quite fast with this, but it still might take 1-3 working days depending on the country, although I have heard from a guy who claimed to get a (temporary) passport the same day in the evening.
2. You can enter through a Schenghen country which is more lax than Germany, and then travel to Germany via intra-Schenghen flight or train. In Italy, for example, in half of my entries they didn't even stamp my passport on entry, and I assume they'd care less about having no space in your passport, while in Germany or Switzerland you can actually be refused entry.
3. If you have visas in your passport which you did not use, you might try to carefully peel them off. **This is the last resort option for a life-or-death situation**, as you have a very good chance to damage your passport completely, and might not be able to even return to the US. Note that some visas will have a stump "a visa was here" under it, and that removing a full-page visa is typically very difficult (but I've seen it being done, so it is not impossible).

Theoretically you may also be denied boarding by the airline if the agent at check in is curious enough, and gets through your passport and finds out there is no empty space there

Comment: Re Point 3: you can never be denied entry to your country of citizenship.
You might be inconvenienced (but difficulties proving you are a citizen), but at the end of the day citizens have right of abode. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43903

Comment: This is only true once you get to the passport control of your home country. However the airline can easily refuse to fly you with a damaged passport - or a passport control at departing country can refuse you through with a damaged passport - so you won't be able to get there.

Comment: I would never consider doing #3. Even if you manage to peel off the visa, the page will be all sticky from the glue and look suspicious.

Comment: @GeorgeY. If stuck in Europe with such a passport, try taking a ferry from France to Ireland. While Ireland is not in Schengen, the passport checks on such a ferry are unlikely to be very rigorous. And there are US passport controls at Dublin and Shannon airports.

Comment: There's another option: travel to the other country and hope they'll squeeze the stamp in on a full page.  I have many pages that are overcrowded with stamps despite the fact that my passport has several empty pages.  Any border officer who would do that is extremely unlikely to refuse entry because of a lack of empty pages.

Comment: @pnuts: same as entering; fly from Germany to Italy or Spain, and leave from there. Or, as **phoog** suggested above, leave through some place like Schiphol where the lines to passport control out of Schengen area are long and passport control tends to be rather formal on the way out.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get what exactly you're asking for then. I thought you asked how'd he leave Germany.

Comment: @MikeScott: wouldn't he then have to get an Irish entry stamp as well in this case (which is rather HUGE)?

Comment: @GeorgeY. He might, or he might not. I'm not sure, for that particular case. Travelling from France to the UK by ferry, your passport will be stamped. From the UK to France, it's not likely that the French authorities will even look at your passport. I don't know whether Ireland is more like France or the UK in this respect.