# Can I re-enter the US from Mexico with just a learner driving permit?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, mexico, identity-cards

I recently crossed into Mexico from the US, forgot to bring my passport. Could I go back using my learner driving permit? I am 17 years old.

OP comment: US citizen, born and raised in Arizona.

Comment: Are you saying you want to go from Mexico to the US, or the other way around?  What is your citizenship?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sounds like OP was able to enter Mexico from the US but needs to get back now.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/what-docs-to-show-if-im-a-us-citizen-with-no-us-passport-but-with-another-non

Comment: Nate I'm trying to set back into the US

Comment: @NateEldredge I was born and raised in Arizona

Comment: As long as you could prove you're really American

Comment: Strange enough that you managed to get into Mexico without your passport - they surely want to hear the story how that worked, in detail. It is doubtful that a learner's permit is enough. If you are a US citizen, they (theoretically) cannot keep you from entering the US, but it can be a lengthy thing, and it's your task to prove it. It could also happen that they think you are lying (being really Mexican), and treat you accordingly - that probably happens several times a day.

Comment: Also as far as I know, Mexico has passport control when you're leaving the country. They are very unlikely to be satisfied with a learner permit from US. Especially if it doesn't even have your photo, as it is the case with Californian ones.

Comment: @Aganju: For many years, Mexico imposed no border checks at all on people entering Mexico by land from the US. One could drive from San Diego into Tijuana without ever stopping, much less showing a passport or any other document.  I haven't heard that this has changed.

Comment: Because of your age, you may want to ask your parents to go the US side of the border crossing, bringing your passport, theirs, etc., anything else. You will be questioned, as a learners permit is not valid for border purposes, but having parent(s) & documents on the other side may shorten the ordeal. They will probably be summoned to ID you, esp as you're a minor.