# Can I enter the USA with a naturalization certificate and foreign passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I do have my oath ceremony scheduled for February 27th,2020 early morning
I know that I will surrender my green card and get my naturalization certificate.
my problem is next day on 28th i am scheduled to travel to Spain .
I will use my Peruvian passport as identification
will my naturalization certificate can help to enter to USA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What documents to show if I'm a US citizen with no US passport to re-enter the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/what-documents-to-show-if-im-a-us-citizen-with-no-us-passport-to-re-enter-the-u)

Comment: what "oath ceremony"? are you becoming a US citizen? Is the question that you won't have a passport the next day but you won't have your green card either? This is not clear at the moment.

Comment: I suspect this plan won’t work. Advice on https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/naturalization-ceremonies  states ‘please allow sufficient time between your naturalization ceremony and any planned travel to receive your passport’. Your problem could be that the airline may not accept your Peruvian passport plus certificate as sufficient to allow you to board. It would be worth contacting the airline you’re travelling with to check.

Comment: They won’t allow you to board your return trip in Spain. Although not recommended, of course you could get a US passport at the USA embassy in Spain. Don’t know how long it will take though and I bet they won’t like your modus operandi however they will have no choice. Carry your Naturalization Certificate along.

Comment: @Crazydre ok, I'll delete my previous comment.  But it seems that Peruvians require visas for Canada, and I suspect that applying for a Canadian visa would be at least as time consuming as getting a US passport.  While the US law carries no penalties, if the flight is subject to a pre-departure check by CBP, they could prevent OP from boarding.

Comment: @Crazydre what exactly does TIMATIC say about this?  Perhaps I am entering the documents incorrectly, but I can't get anything that would allow it.

Comment: @phoog Oops, it'd appear the CBSA has now had IATA remove that exemption from TIMATIC. I take back all I wrote then - getting a US passport in SPain will be the only option

Comment: I'm not an American but I would think that the oath you are planning to take on the 27th precludes you from using the Peruvian passport the next day as part of it is that "I hereby declare, on oath, that I absolutely and entirely renounce and abjure all allegiance and fidelity to any foreign prince, potentate, state, or sovereignty, of whom or which I have heretofore been a subject or citizen.."   Use of another nation's passport would suggest that you have not, in fact, renounced that other nation's citizenship.

Comment: @C'estMoi it's quite well established that the oath does not actually require people naturalizing in the US to renounce any other citizenship.  See for example [Afroyim v. Rusk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroyim_v._Rusk).

Answer (score 10):

You cannot fly back to the US with your naturalisation certificate.

The only solution is getting an emergency passport at the US embassy in Madrid.

Answer (score 1):

Are you applying for dual citizenship? Are you renouncing your Peruvian citizenship once you take the oath for US citizenship? What is the exact scenario with your citizenship. If I am understanding your question, your current passport will become null and void. If you are not a citizen of Peru, you can not travel on a Peruvian passport.

You can, however, apply for an emergency US passport. Since you are a new citizen, I do not know how long it will take. As a born-citizen, my emergency passport took less than 8 hours. You will have to go to the passport office in person, as soon as they open for the day. That may mean delaying your flight.

Comment: Where on Earth is it implied that OP's renouncing their Peruvian citizenship.

Comment: @Crazydre - The first two sentences in the answer address this. There are question marks at the end of each sentence. Dual citizenship or renouncing their Peruvian citizenship would be the only options that I know of when taking the oath of US citizenship. My in-laws and numerous friends have gone through the US naturalization process. And I’m related to an immigration attorney. I’ll ask them about another option. Do you know of a third option? Otherwise, why on Earth would you assume the OP has not followed one of the two options mentioned above?

Comment: I don’t know where the OP lives. But, if I were a betting man, I would wager that it would be worth the hassle to call the nearest official passport office to him and ask about the process to get an emergency passport before he leaves the states. P.S. I call it an emergency passport. In my case, it was an absolutely real and permanent passport done on an emergency, expedited basis. I walked in in the morning with my paperwork, pictures and processing fee (plus a very reasonable, nominal expediting fee). And, walked out in the afternoon with a very real ten year passport.

Comment: Presumably OP is becoming a dual citizen

Answer (score 1):

> will my naturalization certificate can help to enter to USA

Yes if entering via land or sea border and aged 15/18 or under. See https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-3618?language=en_US for more details:

> **Land or Sea Travel**: U.S. citizens entering the United States by land or sea are required to present a valid WHTI-compliant document, which include:
>
> - U.S. Passports
> - U.S. Passport Cards
> - Enhanced Driver's Licenses
> - Enhanced Tribal Card (ETC)
> - Trusted Traveler Cards (Global Entry*, NEXUS, SENTRI, or FAST
> - Military Identification Cards (for members of the U.S. armed official maritime business)
>
> ***** The Global Entry (GE) card is only an ENTRY document and may not be used to enter Canada, Mexico or Adjacent Island.
>
> Military personnel traveling under orders may present photo ID and orders. Family members must present a passport (with the exception of children 15 and younger arriving by land or sea.)
>
> **Children:** U.S. citizen children ages 15 and under arriving by land or sea from a contiguous territory (Canada or Mexico) may present an original or copy of his or her birth certificate (issued by the Vital Records Department in the state where he or she was born), a Consular Report of Birth Abroad, or a **Naturalization Certificate**. If the child is a newborn and the actual birth certificate has not arrived from the Vital Records Department, we will accept a Hospital issued birth certificate.
>
> **Groups of Children**: A U.S. citizen children between the ages of 16-18 arriving by land or sea from contiguous territory and traveling with an adult supervised school group, religious group, social or cultural organization, or sports team, may also present an original or copy of his or her birth certificate, a Consular Report of Birth Abroad, or a **Naturalization Certificate**.
>
> For more specific information regarding passport documents, please contact the [National Passport Information Center](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/contact-us.html).
>
> For documentation requirements regarding cruises, please see our FAQ on "[What Documents do I need for Cruises](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-74?language=en_US) "

I'm guessing the certificate of naturalization also helps if you're over 18 and end up in secondary at the land border due to lack of accepted documents (US passport, Enhanced Driver's License, Global Entry, etc.), but that'd be great if someone could confirm.

FYI: [What's the legal consequence of leaving the United States without using one's U.S. passport?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/79459/31)